# enable disable radio button field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, radio-button

I am working on a data application in which i need to use radio button field.

The functionality of radio button fields depends on the response of web service.

I need to control the selection of the radio buttons. that is, if I want to disable one of the two radio button if response is negative for it and user can't use that button.

Is it possible to make inactive the radio button of any radio group.

I had already used methods like field.setEnable(false);

[image]

Comment: if(negative){ then dont add the radio button  to the screen} else{ add the radio button to the screen}

Comment: I can not do that, I can not hide or delete the field from the UI. I need to make it inactive.

Comment: add the un wanted radio button into an horizontal field manager. then set the horizontal field manager's focus to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Field.NON_FOCUSABLE` style in the `RadioButtonField`'s constructor to make the field non-focusable when you create it. You cannot change this property in runtime if you use this method.

To change the focusable/non focusable property of the field in runtime, override the `RadioButtonField`'s `isFocusable()` method, and return `true` or `false` depending on your web service's response.

```
public boolean isFocusable()
{
    return shouldTheRadioButtonBeEnabled;
}
```

Returning `false` from `isFocusable()` will make your field non-focusable.